# Change <RadioGroup> Orientation onClick or isChecked

Tags: java, android, jquery, xml

I am new to android programming and I am trying change the orientation of my RadioGroup when one of the buttons within the group is clicked.

For example,

The RadioGroup(id: ***groupOne***) will have two RadioButtons,

one named "horizontal" (id: ***hor***)

and

one named "vertical" (id: ***vert***)

The RadioGroup Orientation by default will be horizontal

when "vertical" is clicked the RadioGroup will change from a horizontal orientation to a vertical and will remain that way as long as the ***vert*** RadioButton is checked.

and likewise for the ***hor*** RadioButton

**note: I am using a LinearLayout for the app.

activity_main.xml :

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/groupOne"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/hor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Horizontal"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/vert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vertical"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

I have tried two ways to get this done

Approach Number one: (Main Activity.java)

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {



    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    RadioGroup myLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.groupOne);

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.hor:
            if (checked)

                myLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.groupOne);
                myLayout.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

            break;
        case R.id.vert:
            if (checked)


                myLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.groupOne);
                myLayout.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

            break;

        }
}
```

Approach Number Two: (MainActivity.java)

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view) {


    RadioButton horizontal = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.hor);
    RadioButton vertical = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.vert);

    if (horizontal.isChecked()) {
        View.OnClickListener first_radio_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RadioGroup myLayout;
                myLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.groupOne);
                myLayout.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
            }
        };
    }
    else if (vertical.isChecked()) {
        View.OnClickListener second_radio_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RadioGroup myLayout;
                myLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.groupOne);
                myLayout.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            }
        };
    }
```

Neither of these have worked and have both resulted in either radio buttons when checked/clicked do nothing or it just crashes if either are checked. In some cases it doesn't even run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)